# Proving the convergence of $\sum \frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Again I need your help in proving the convergence of a series, this time with
$$\sum \frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}.$$

I thought to apply the root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}} = \frac{n!}{n^{4}} \sim \frac{1}{n^4} \to 0 < 1.$$

So, the series must converge. But, thanks to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28%28n%21%29%5En%29%2F%28n%5E%284*n%29%29), I know that it DOESN'T.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: $\frac{n!}{n^{4}} \sim \frac{1}{n^4} $?!

Comment: "Where is my mistake?" When you state that $\frac{n!}{n^{4}} \sim \frac{1}{n^4}$.

Comment: I thought $\exists{N}$ such as $n! < n^4, \forall n > N$.

Comment: @hlapointe: $7!=  5040 < 7^4 = 2401$ is incorrect.

Comment: Can we say that generally, $n! > n^k, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, and $n!/n^4\sim (n-4)!$.

Comment: @hlapointe Take $n$ large enough so that $n-5\gt 1$ and $n-4\gt \frac n2$ (how big is this?)  Then $n!\gt (n-4)\cdot(n-3)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-1)\cdot n$ $\gt (\frac n2)\cdot(\frac n2)\cdot(\frac n2)\cdot(\frac n2)\cdot n$ $=n^5/16$.  Now, choose $n\gt 16$...

Comment: $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)!$, so that $n!/n^4=(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)·(n-4)!$. Selecting a lower bound for $n$ you obtain twosided bounds for the first three factors.

Comment: $n!$ is a product of $n$ things, several of which are pretty close to $n$. $n^4$ is only a product of $4$ things, each equal to $n$.  $\frac{n!}{n^4}$ is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may easily prove that
$$
n!>2 \times n^4, \quad n\geq7,
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}>2^n \to +\infty
$$

and your initial series is **divergent**.

Answer (score 0):

On your root test, if you let $n\rightarrow\infty$ then you can use Stirling's approximation and:
$$ \frac{n!}{n^4}\sim \frac{n ln(n)-n}{n^4}$$
And you want 
$$\frac{n ln(n)-n}{n^4}<1$$
$$\frac{nln(n)}{n^4}-\frac{n}{n^4}<1$$
$$ln(n)-1<n^3$$
And we know that is true just by looking at the graphs of the RHS and LHS. If you want a more rigorous proof then define $f(n)=ln(n)-1-n^3$ and if you take $\frac{d}{dx}f(n)$ you'll see it is constantly decreasing and $f(n)$ is always smaller than cero; and so the initial condition of $n!<n^4$ is not true.